# PostgreSQL Use a value from a select statement as a variable within that same statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty complex SQL statement in my PostgreSQL database which I use as a basis in several views. But in this statement, a sum aggregate function is called multiple times. I'm now seeking to optimize these views by getting rid of summarizing these values multiple times by using a variable.

I know I can use @myvalue = 1, but this is in pgScript and it can't be used in a view as it is pgScript.

I have read about abusing the config settings to store a variable in, but I don't know how this plays with views and I'm not really fond of such hacks.

The part from the SQL I want to store in a variable is `sum(v."Surface")::double precision` which is repeated multiple times.

If there are any other suggestions for optimizing this SQL I'm all for it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mydb."MyTable" AS 
SELECT p."Id",
    v."FunctionInt",
    v."TypeInt",
    sum(v."Surface") AS "SurfaceTotaal",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."Average") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "Average",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."E") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "E",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."E1") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "E1",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."E2") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "E2",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."E3") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "E3",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."M") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "M",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."M1") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "M1",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."M2") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "M2",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."M3") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "M3",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."G") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "G",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."G1") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "G1",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."G2") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "G2",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."G3") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "G3",
    round((sum(v."Surface"::double precision * v."G4") / sum(v."Surface")::double precision)::numeric, 1) AS "G4"
FROM mydb."PTable" p,
LATERAL ( 
    SELECT 
        v."Id",
        v."Surface",
        v."FunctionInt",
        v."TypeInt",
        r."YearGroupInt",
        r."Average",
        r."En" AS "E",
        r."En1" AS "E1",
        r."En2" AS "E2",
        r."En3" AS "E3",
        r."Mi" AS "M",
        r."Mi1" AS "M1",
        r."Mi2" AS "M2",
        r."Mi3" AS "M3",
        r."Gz" AS "G",
        r."Gz1" AS "G1",
        r."Gz2" AS "G2",
        r."Gz3" AS "G3",
        r."Gz4" AS "G4"
    FROM mydb."VTable" v
    JOIN mydb."RTable" r ON 
            v."FunctionInt" = r."FunctionInt" 
            AND v."TypeInt" = r."TypeInt" 
            AND v."YearGroupInt" = r."YearGroupInt"
    WHERE v."PId" = p."Id") v
GROUP BY p."Id", v."FunctionInt", v."TypeInt";
```

Comment: `create function(var) returns table`?..

Comment: You don't need to "optimize" this SQL. Even if this `sum(v."Surface")` appears 1000 times in your query, the optimizer is smart enought and knows that this is the same value, and calculates it **only once**, not 1000 times.

Comment: @krokodilko, I was hoping for something like this, great, that pretty much answers my question, any other suggestions apart from the numerous casts that I intent to get rid of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `sum(v."Surface")::double precision` is calculated multiple times is incorrect. The planner handles that, test it for yourself.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,1E7) AS t;
```

Then..

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT sum(t) FROM foo;
```

Now, try it with two (no appreciable slow down)

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT sum(t), sum(t) FROM foo;
```

Planner does not fold constants though,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT sum(t), sum(t+0) FROM foo;
```

Comment: I would never put an aggregate in a view that is used elsewhere as a base for other views. The planner can't push `WHERE` conditions down in that. And, moreover.  I also would not do casting like that. If they need to be double precision, store them as a double precision. Keep them as a double precision. Use a [math function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) if you need more or less precision. Your use of surface also tells me you should probably be using PostGIS or cube, or geometry base types.

Comment: I agree, you misunderstand, I use the code in multiple views, I do not reference one view in another (came to the same conclusion you are stating the hard way). Surface is a data field of type integer stored in a database I use, so it is not a geometry type